# how can i set height from 0 to 'auto' within @react-spring useTransition?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, height, react-spring

I used useTransition hook to add animation to a list element, and its child element's height is not a fixed number. if I set `{from:{height:0},enter:{height:'auto'}`, the element lose animation.

I want the children in transition animation div have a dynamic height property, any conclusions? :b

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to animate between an `AnimatedValue` and an `AnimatedString`. In **React Spring**, the `height` property is expected to be a numeric value for smooth interpolation.

To resolve this, you can use a workaround by animating the `maxHeight` property instead of `height`.

The `maxHeight` property can be set to a large enough value when you want to show the content and set to 0 when you want to hide it. This way, you're essentially controlling the visibility with the `maxHeight` property while still achieving the desired animation effect.

Answer (score 1):

the reasong cause this problem is that `transition` doesnt work with `height:auto`.

I found some tricks to solve this problem.

1. use `max-height` instead of `height`
2. use `grid` display, and toggle `grid-template-rows` between`0fr` to `1fr`
3. get element innerHeight when mount. An [official expample](https://codesandbox.io/s/v1i1t?file=/src/App.tsx:693-699)

Comment: https://juejin.cn/post/7196843994030342200

Comment: The max-height animation works but suffers from scroll-bar flickering problems. The grid-template-rows animation on the other hand is smooth and works nicely. Thanks for summarizing the options.